# run yii framework on ubuntu 16.06

Tags: php, html, mysql

I was introduced to yii framework recently on someone's computer. I really liked that framework and therefore I ran fast to install it on my ubuntu 16.04 LTS. But since then, it has been trouble to run yii, I dont know why. In the first place I installed the composer,

```
sudo apt-get install curl
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

I then used composer to install Composer asset plugin

```
root@miller:/home/miller# composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
```

It generated autoload files (atleast that is what the terminal said).
When it came to installing yii2 basic and advanced templates, the whole story changed. Some tutorial advised me to move to my localhost web root folder with this command so that I could Install the templates

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/
```

This did not work so I changed to:

```
cd /var/www/html
```

Perfect! there I was in the web root folder.
The last command that I ran to install the templates was this;

composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic

and this is the error I got (I still get it even now) from the terminal;

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
```

The "http://packagist.org/p/yiisoft/yii2-codeception%247d4410e5dca24aea872a0c6b775ab397344bdbd02d76969367de08d7e8439116.json" file could not be d
  ownloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

I have tried to load (localhost/basic/web) but it finds nothing. I have also used this tutorial[enter link description here](http://www.freetuts.org/tutorial/view?id=4)

Please help

Comment: try this link http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/67312-composer-error-500/

Answer (score 0):

Try this please make sure composer installed in your ubuntu

sudo composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic

or

php composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic

Comment: The first one gave me this error: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
The second one said this: Could not open input file: composer anything else?

Answer (score -1):

Try this guide [installing Yii2 on Cloud](http://www.cloudways.com/blog/install-yii-2-framework-on-cloud/) this will help you out in it.